# Browsers not observing changes to data-*, CSS attribute selector properties not rendering

Tags: jquery, css, dom, rendering, custom-attributes

Given this CSS:

```
[data-myplugin-object="blue-window"]{
    background-color: #00f;
}

[data-myplugin-object="red-window"]{
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

And this jQuery:

```
$('[data-myplugin-object="blue-window"]').each(function(event){
    $(this).data({
        'myplugin-object': 'red-window'
    });
});
```

And this HTML snippet:

```
<div data-myplugin-object="blue-window">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Now, one would expect that when the jQuery snippet is executed (*properly deferred until page load is complete of course*) my blue window (*which does initially render as blue*) would turn red.

Nope, it certainly does not; and using Firebug and Developer Tools in Firefox and Chrome respectively, I can't observe any changes to the `data-*` attributes.

In order for the browser (*and DOM toolboxes for that matter*) to observe changes, do I need to revert to `.attr()` or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jQuery.data()` attributes are not actually stored on the DOM object in jQuery.  The DOM object is tagged with a unique jQuery ID and the actual data is stored in a separate javascript data structure.  Among other reasons, jQuery does it this way to prevent circular reference memory leak bugs that can happen in some browsers when data values are references to other DOM objects.

If you want to change the actual DOM attribute, I'd suggest setting the attribute directly yourself like this:

```
obj.attr("data-myplugin-object", "red-window");
```

Though, for what you're doing, I think most people would use adding/removing/changing CSS class names, not custom attributes as that is the common way of changing which CSS rules apply to an object.

```
<div id="myObj" class="blueWindow">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>

.blueWindow {background-color: #00F;}
.redWindow  {background-color: #F00;}

 $("#myObj").removeClass("blueWindow").addClass("redWindow");
```

Or if there are no other classes on the object:

```
 $("#myObj").attr("class", "redWindow");
```

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 - CSS classes are obviously more fitting for the case of exclusively styling the elements, however I'm working on a plugin and wanted to implement some default styles based on the semantic relevance of custom attributes (*relevance to the layout*) These of course are intended to be overridden with CSS selectors of higher specificity (*such as `.classes`*) In any case, if the `.attr()` method is my best bet, then that's the direction I'll go. Does `.data()` provide any other underlying functionality that may be lost with this change? (*aside from supporting maps, etc.*)

Comment: The main additionality functionality I know of for `.data()` is related to memory links when using things other than simple strings (e.g. object references).  Not only does it prevent circular DOM references, but it also makes sure any things that have a reference via `.data()` are cleaned up if you remove the DOM object through jQuery.  If you're just using strings, I don't think it offers much additional functionality for you.  If you are doing it a lot, you might want to look at performance and memory usage of a DOM attribute vs. the jQuery way.